# MySQLi Multiple Queries, accessing second array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a multi-query MySQLi statement that uses multiple queries and when using `var_dump` brings back the following:

**var_dump of array**:

```
array(1) { ["company"]=> string(8) "ffr3e456" ["high_1"]=> string(8) "8.32465" }
array(2) { ["company"]=> string(8) "gg8751hw" ["high_2"]=> string(7) "7.66574" }
```

The code I am using to display the array in a PHP file picks up the first array (i.e. the content of `high_1` information but not the second.

**code**

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    for ($p=1; $p<=2; $p++)
                         {
                         echo number_format($row["high_".$p],2);
```

The HTML output shows the data from the first array but not the second.  I am sure I am overlooking something, any advice and feedback welcomed.

Comment: Can you show the code that actually does the query and fetches the results?

Comment: Your keys have the names `high_1` and `high_2`, not `novhigh_1` and `novhigh_2`. Why don't you get those values with a single `UNION` statement instead?

Comment: Added the preceeding code.  Adjusted code so `high_`1 and `high_2` match.  Can't use `UNION` on this occasion.

Comment: And what produces the output that you provided at the top? Certainly not `var_dump($row);`.

Comment: @PatrickQ - it is actually a var_dump - for simplicity I've kept the amount of data in the array to two simple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$C = array_merge($A, $B);
```

You can read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Thanks @ssergei - however, both arrays are within the `$row` variable - no idea how to merge or combine them.

Comment: `$A = $row[0]; 
$B = $row[1];`

Comment: Could you provide a `print_r` of `$row` so we could see how the array is constructed?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed the SQL statement that returns the results.

Are the returned arrays in separate $row results?

In that case you need to iterate through each $row result, something like:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
 for ($p=1; $p<=2; $p++)
 {
  echo number_format($row["novhigh_".$p],2);
 }
}
```

On a side note: It looks like the key definition inside the arrays is not logical, why not have the same key value for the "novhigh" element?